# Excel Interop: Cell Double Click Event

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, excel-interop

I want to know if there exists a way with which I can open a Winform once I double click on a particular cell (range of cells) in a sheet.  Using C# code. Basically is there an event handler for double click event on a particular cell and how can that handler be used to open a Winform.

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook;
```

This is how I open the excel. Now assuming I have to open a windows form when 'B2' is double clicked, how do I do it?

Thanks,

Comment: Where do you open your excel sheet? From .Net app or from Microsoft Excel?

Comment: From .NET using Excel Interop calls

Comment: And how do you display the excel cells? Using `DataGridView`?

Comment: Can you some codes? so we can fully understand your questions

Comment: I open Excel itself and display @Ian

Comment: Hope the above code helps @Juran